# Add additional elements from a dictionary to the XML during serialization in C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

A part of the XML looks like this.

```
<element>
    <subelment1>text</subelement1>
    <subelement2>text2</subelement2>
    ...
</element>
```

It has a lot of sub elements.

I would like to add additional elements during the serialization, but the number and name is always different. 
So it will be something like this:

```
<element>
    <subelment1>text</subelement1>
    <subelement2>text2</subelement2>
    ...
    <additionalelement1>element1text</additionalelement1>
    <additionalelement2>element2text</additionalelement2>
    ...
</element>
```

The additional elements are stored in a dictionary, where the element name is the key.

Is there a way to accomplish this with the XmlSerializer or any other serializer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post this solution a lot :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication34
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement element = doc.Descendants("element").FirstOrDefault();

            Dictionary<string,string> dict = element.Elements().GroupBy(x => x.Name.LocalName, y => (string)y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is element to dictionary direction, but still I got the method. Thank you.